# Cuál es el significado de la palabra "hay" en "qué hay sobre"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

Era en un tebeo que estoy leyendo.

Adición: el contexto: Una persona regresa con comida por solo una otra, y un otro personaje dice "¡¿Qué hay sobre la comida que nosotros queríamos comer?!"

Comment: Debes darnos el contexto mejor (una o dos frases antes y después) para que te podamos ayudar.  También, sería mejor hacer otra pregunta sobre la diferencia entre *tebeo* y *cómic*, ya que StackExchange está optimizado para tener una pregunta y una mejor respuesta en cada entrada.

Comment: La pregunta sobre cómic y tebeo vino de buscando por la traducción de "comic" en inglés.

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para eliminar la segunda pregunta (sobre las definiciones de "cómico" y "tebeo"). Si quieres hacer otra pregunta sobre eso, estaría bien, pero te recomiendo que ves un diccionario antes.

Comment: Ese tebeo no es de España, ¿verdad?. Aquí esa frase haría pensar que encima de la comida había algo (otra comída) que queríamos comer. Por cierto @keroro, la diferencia entre tebeo o comic no afecta a la pregunta ya que son lo mismo (tebeo 'TBO' era una marca -como si hablases de marvell- que de lo famosa que llegó a ser haciendo estas revistas terminó dando nombre al conjunto de éstas. Posteriormente con la llegada del anglicismo comic se ha empezado a llamar a los TBOs por éste nombre)

Answer (score 4):

Respecto a tu primer duda:

El uso en este caso del verbo *haber* alude a la existencia o a la situación en la que se encuentra algo o alguien, en este caso:

> ¿Qué *hay* sobre la comida que (nosotros) queríamos comer!

El verbo haber puede sustituirse con *pasa* o *sucede* (que en vez de *sobre* requeriría la preposición *con*).

Lo que quiere saber la persona que pregunta es la causa de la ausencia de dicha comida ¿que ha sucedido con la comida? ¿donde está o porque no está lista aun?

En cuanto a lo del tebeo, se trata de un españolismo para referirse a una historieta o cómic, cuyo origen ya aclaró Diego. Fuera de España es raro escuchar que alguien diga tebeo y más raro aun que te entiendan, sobre todo si lo comentas con los chicos que gustan de esas lecturas.

Answer (score 2):

Ese "hay" es de "haber". Es una forma de preguntar "qué *existe* sobre [algo]" o "qué *se sabe* acerca de [algo]".

Creo que no hay mucha diferencia entre cómic y tebeo. Siempre pensé que *tebeo* era la forma española de llamar al cómic. Había una publicación llamada TBO http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TBO_(comics)

Creo que de ahí viene el nombre.

Comment: Por cierto, lo correcto sería preguntar "**cuál** es el significado de XXX"

Comment: Entonces, cuál es el significado entre "qué sobre," y "qué hay sobre?"

Comment: @keroro «Qué sobre» puede tener varios significados.  Puede ser en plan *¡qué (gran) sobre!* para describir una carta que te ha llegado en un sobre muy bonito, o como *¿qué sobre (quieres)?* para pedir que el escuchante elija entre varios sobres.  También puede deber ser *que sobre (mucho)*, siendo una exhortación para que haya exceso, o una versión errónea de *¿qué sobra (aquí)?* que quiere saber de tal exceso.  También puede ser el inicio de una oración com *¡qué sobre (algo)?* como interjección indignante para saber lo que trataba de tal *algo*.